# Insert List in Database

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access-2010

I have a list in richtextbox ex:

```
dogs
cats 
books
other
```

how to insert in table "animals", column "home" one for lines?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this using [ODBC](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310988):

```
string connectionString ="yourConnectionString"
using (DbConnection conn = new OdbcConnection(connectionString))
using (DbCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
{
  cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Animals(home) VALUES (@animal)";
  DbParameter p = cmd.CreateParameter();
  p.ParameterName = "@animal";
  cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
  conn.Open();
  using (DbTransaction tran = conn.BeginTransaction())
 {
     cmd.Transaction = tran;
     try
     {
         foreach (string line in MyRichTextBox.Lines)
         {
            p.Value = line;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
         }
         tran.Commit();
         conn.Close();
     }
     catch (Exception e)
     {
         tran.Rollback();
        throw(e);
     }
 }
```

}

Comment: Please give the asker an opportunity to figure out their answer on their own.

Comment: @jolly - So you're expecting someone to give you a working code example without doing any work on your own? Color me surprised.

Comment: i have insert a connection Provider=MSDataShape;Data Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=Database\\Database.mdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=1234